Cordova 12 Cordova-Android v13 Splash screen not showing
I've updated myCordova to version 12 and cordova-android platform to version 13 and suddenly the custom splash-screen I had added and was working just fine doesn't show anymore.
I just get the default Cordova one.
This is my config.xml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="26" id="com.xxxxxxxxx.app" ios-CFBundleVersion="2.0" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>XXXXX Pizza</name>
    <description>
        XXXXX Pizza app
    </description>
    <author email="info@xxxxxxx.com" href="https://xxxxxxx.com">
        App Development Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="gap:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="file:*" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <!-- <preference name="AndroidGradlePluginVersion" value="8.7.0" /> -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="34" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xffffffff" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="12.0.0" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="false" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" foreground="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" />
        <icon background="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" foreground="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" />

        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-hdpi/splash.png" density="hdpi"/>
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-ldpi/splash.png" density="ldpi"/>
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-mdpi/splash.png" density="mdpi"/>
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-xhdpi/splash.png" density="xhdpi"/>
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-xxhdpi/splash.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-xxxhdpi/splash.png" density="xxhdpi"/>

        <!-- Landscape -->
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-land-hdpi/splash.png" density="land-hdpi" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-land-ldpi/splash.png" density="land-ldpi" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-land-mdpi/splash.png" density="land-mdpi" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/splash.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-land-xxhdpi/splash.png" density="land-xxhdpi" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" src="res/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/splash.png" density="land-xxxhdpi" />

        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi/ic_stat_notifications.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi/ic_stat_notifications.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi/ic_stat_notifications.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_stat_notifications.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_notifications.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/notification_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_stat_notifications.png" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/notification_icon_large.png" />

        <resource-file src="res/sound/blackberry.mp3" target="app/src/main/res/raw/blackberry.mp3" />
        <resource-file src="res/sound/crystal.mp3" target="app/src/main/res/raw/crystal.mp3" />
        <resource-file src="res/sound/msn.mp3" target="app/src/main/res/raw/msn.mp3" />
        <resource-file src="build-extras.gradle" target="app/build-extras.gradle" />
        <config-file parent="/manifest/application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
        </config-file>
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="20" src="res/icon/ios/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="res/icon/ios/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="res/icon/ios/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="40" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="1024" src="res/icon/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <icon height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="29" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/sound/blackberry.caf" />
        <resource-file src="res/sound/crystal.caf" />
        <resource-file src="res/sound/msn.caf" />
        <resource-file src="res/pn-actions.json" />
        <config-file parent="NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>Need location access to find stores nearby</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>Need location access to find stores nearby</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSUserTrackingUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>Your data will be used to show your personalized offers and discount codes to be used during checkout.</string>
        </config-file>
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    </platform>
</widget>

I've copied all the splash screen images for the various formats in cordova/res/screen/android

This is my package.json
{
  "name": "com.xxxxxxxx.app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Four Star Pizza App",
  "author": "xxxxxxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "cordova-ios": "NUXT_ENV_MAP_API_KEY=$MAP_API_KEY_IOS npm run build-spa && npm run generate && npm run replace-relative-paths && npm run copy-cordova && npm run run-ios;",
    "cordova-android": "NUXT_ENV_MAP_API_KEY=$MAP_API_KEY_ANDROID npm run build-spa && npm run generate && npm run replace-relative-paths && npm run copy-cordova && npm run run-android;",
    "build-spa": "nuxt build --spa",
    "replace-relative-paths": "replace '/nuxtfiles/' 'nuxtfiles/' dist --recursive && replace '/assets/' 'nuxtfiles/' dist --recursive && replace '(href|src|\"href\"|\"src\")=\"/' '$1=\"../' dist --recursive && replace '(href|src|\"href\"|\"src\"):\"/' '$1:\"../' dist --recursive",
    "copy-cordova": "cp -R dist/* cordova/www/ && echo COPIED",
    "clear-cordova": "rm -R cordova/www/*",
    "run-ios": "cd cordova && cordova run ios",
    "run-android": "cd cordova && cordova run android",
    "serve-cordova": "cd cordova && cordova serve",
    "cordova-live-build": "npm run build-spa && npm run generate && npm run replace-relative-paths && npm run copy-cordova && cd cordova && cordova build",
    "cordova-live-run-ios": "npm run cordova-live-build && npm run cordova-ios",
    "cordova-live-run-android": "npm run cordova-live-build && npm run cordova-android",
    "watch": "npm-watch",
    "resgen": "cd cordova && crgen -p android,ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/components": "^1.1.0",
    "@nuxt/core": "^2.14.7",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.4",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^8.2.2",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.2",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.10.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^9.8.1",
    "ios-deploy": "^1.12.2",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "npm-watch": "^0.7.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.13.3",
    "nuxt-gmaps": "^1.2.10",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-geolocation-api": "^0.1.17",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.21",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "vuexfire": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "replace": "^1.2.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.8",
    "stylus-loader": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "watch": {
    "cordova-live-build": {
      "patterns": [
        "{src,assets,components,layouts,store,mixins,servermiddleware,plugins}/*.js"
      ],
      "extensions": "vue,js,scss",
      "quiet": false
    }
  }
}

and this is the package.json inside the cordova subfolder
{
    "name": "cordova.demo",
    "displayName": "demoApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "rf": "node scripts/reinstall-firebasex.js"
    },
    "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "cordova-plugin-androidx": "3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": "5.0.2",
        "cordova-support-google-services": "1.4.1",
        "cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix": "1.2.1",
        "google-auth-library": "^6.1.4",
        "ios-sim": "^9.0.0",
        "macos-release": "^3.3.0",
        "nice-try": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": {
                "URL_SCHEME": "com.xxxxxxxxx.app"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-hidden-statusbar-overlay": {},
            "cordova-plugin-idfa": {},
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-support-android-plugin": {},
            "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
                "ANDROIDBLACKLISTSECURESOCKETPROTOCOLS": "SSLv3,TLSv1"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
            "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": {},
            "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
                "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
                "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
                "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
                "FIREBASE_FCM_AUTOINIT_ENABLED": "true",
                "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_WITHOUT_ADS": "false",
                "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ADID_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
                "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_ANALYTICS_STORAGE": "true",
                "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_STORAGE": "true",
                "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_USER_DATA": "true",
                "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_PERSONALIZATION_SIGNALS": "true",
                "ANDROID_ICON_ACCENT": "#FF00FFFF",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_MONITORING": "false",
                "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_TAGMANAGER_VERSION": "18.0.4",
                "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_AUTH_VERSION": "20.7.0",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "21.6.2",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "23.4.1",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CONFIG_VERSION": "21.6.3",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_VERSION": "20.5.2",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "22.3.1",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_INAPPMESSAGING_VERSION": "20.4.2",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_FIRESTORE_VERSION": "24.11.1",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_FUNCTIONS_VERSION": "20.4.0",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_IID_VERSION": "21.1.0",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_INSTALLATIONS_VERSION": "17.2.0",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_VERSION": "18.6.4",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_NDK_VERSION": "18.6.4",
                "ANDROID_GSON_VERSION": "2.9.0",
                "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION": "1.4.2",
                "ANDROID_GRPC_OKHTTP": "1.46.0",
                "IOS_USE_PRECOMPILED_FIRESTORE_POD": "false",
                "IOS_FCM_ENABLED": "true"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "cordova-android": "^13.0.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^6.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "^4.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^8.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^16.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-hidden-statusbar-overlay": "^2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-idfa": "^3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-support-android-plugin": "~2.0.4"
    }
}

If I open the project on Android Studio, I can see that the splashscreen is there.

But for whatever reason, it doesn't appear when I launch the app.
Does anybody else have encountered this issue?

As per the new Android update, it is very complex or perhaps not possible to set a full-screen splash screen. We can only display our splash screen in a rounded circle, according to the Android guidelines found here: Android Splash Screen Guidance.
Here are the steps to set a custom rounded splash screen:

Add this code inside styles.xml:

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#1E1E1F</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">#1E1E1F</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/icon_splash</item>
</style>


Add icon_splash.png inside android/app/src/main/res/drawable/icon_splash.png.

Note: The icon_splash.png size must be 1024 x 1024 px, and the background should be transparent with an 800 x 800 px icon.
Here is the example of icon_splash.png :
See Image
